# How do I read a value from a child component

Tags: angular-dart

I have two components:

```dart
@Component(
  selector: 'parent',
  directives: [
    ChildComponent,
  ],
  templateUrl: 'parent.html',
)
class ParentComponent {
  Result parentResult;
}
```

and

```dart
@Component(
  selector: 'child',
  templateUrl: 'child.html',
)
class ChildComponent {
  @Output()
  Result childResult;
}
```

When `childResult` changes, I want `parentResult` to change to the new value. How can I do this? I tried doing things like:
`<child [parentResult]="childResult">...</child>`
in the `parent.html` file, but none of the combinations I tried worked. I also tried having the child constructor take a ParentComponent, but the injection system didn't like that.

Answer (score 0):

`@Output()` is indeed what you need. But it must be a `Stream` so your parent element can listen to it.

```dart
@Component(
 selector: 'child',
 templateUrl: 'child.html',
)
class ChildComponent implements OnDestroy {
 final _resultController = StreamController<Result>();

 @Input()
 Result result;

 @Output()
 Stream<Result> get onResultChange => _resultController.stream;

 void changeResult(Result newResult) {
   result = newResult;
   onResultChange.add(newResult);
 }

 void ngOnDestroy() {
   // close stream controller to avoid memory leak
   _resultController.close();
 }
}
```

Then bind the Output in your parent component

```html
<child (onResultChange)="result = $event"></child>
```

PS: `(xxx)=""` syntax is use to bind `@Output` of a component. `[xxx]=""` use to set value of an `@Input`